# Change style when rotation the smartphone

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use the react-native-orientation-locker package and I would like to change the style when I rotate the smartphone

I use the state to initialize my style, but this solution I don't think is optimal

here is an example of my code

```
const [styles, setStyles] = useState(Styles(theme, layout))

const changeStyles = (o: OrientationType): void => {
    layout = getDeviceVideoLayout(o) // return 'PORTRAIT or 'LANDSCAPE-LEFT' or 'LANDSCAPE-RIGHT'
// change the rotation of the phone
    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window')
//I update width and height
    theme.layout.width = width
    theme.layout.height = height
// I update the status
    setStyles(Styles(theme, layout))
}

  useDeviceOrientationChange((o) => {
      changeStyles(o)
  })
```

I don't like this solution of the style in the state

an example of my style

```
const StyleCommon = (theme: Theme, bottomSpace: number): StyleGeneral => StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      height: theme.layout.height,
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: theme.colors.black
    },
    actionButtonContainer: {
      width: 50,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(242, 241, 240, 0.3)',
      borderRadius: 12,
      marginBottom: 20
    }
  })
  
const StyleLayoutPortrait = (theme: Theme, bottomSpace: number): StyleLayout => StyleSheet.create({
    actionContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: theme.spacing.sm + theme.layout.insets.bottom + 40 + bottomSpace,
        right: theme.spacing.sm
    }
})

const StyleLayoutLandscapeLeft = (theme: Theme): StyleLayout => StyleSheet.create({
    actionContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: theme.spacing.sm,
        right: theme.spacing.sm
    }
})

const StyleLayoutLandscapeRight = (theme: Theme): StyleLayout => StyleSheet.create({
    actionContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        right: theme.spacing.sm + theme.layout.insets.top,
        top: theme.spacing.sm
    }
})

const Styles = (theme: Theme, layout: VideoLayoutType, bottomSpace: number): Style => {
  if (layout === 'LANDSCAPE-RIGHT') {
    return ({
      ...StyleCommon(theme, bottomSpace),
      ...StyleLayoutLandscapeRight(theme)
    })
  } else if (layout === 'LANDSCAPE-LEFT') {
    return ({
      ...StyleCommon(theme, bottomSpace),
      ...StyleLayoutLandscapeLeft(theme)
    })
  } else {
    return ({
      ...StyleCommon(theme, bottomSpace),
      ...StyleLayoutPortrait(theme, bottomSpace)
    })
  }
}
```

I do not think this solution is optimal, how could I do?

Answer (score 0):

```html
 indicatorContainerProps:{
    position: 'fixed',
    right: '0px',
    bottom: '0%',
    marginBottom: '40%',
    display:'flex',
    justifyContent:'center',
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    "@media (orientation:landscape)": {
      marginBottom: '0px'
    }
```

This example is for Jsx or ReactJs.
You just need to specify the some class name like text

```
text:{
    position: 'fixed',
    right: '0px',
    bottom: '0%',
    marginBottom: '40%',
    display:'flex',
    justifyContent:'center',
    flexDirection:'row',
    alignItems:'center',
    "@media (orientation:landscape)": { //here you can change based on orientation 
      marginBottom: '0px'
    }
```